# Angular 2 JWT - why 2 requests?

Tags: angular, spring-security, jwt

I was playing with this project https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample and secure call looks strange. If I click button to make a secure call I can see that two requests are made. First one doesn't include Bearer with jwt in header and response status is 204. The second one is normal request with all necessary information. Why we need this first request ? It's problematic in my spring security app since I don't have bearer there

Comment: Most likely the first one was CORS pre-flight request.

Comment: The CORS request is probably an `OPTIONS` request. You can respond differently to this one (just respond with the CORS headers).

Comment: Can you post a HAR file of both requests? (https://auth0.com/docs/har)